# How to save python ogr2ogr shapefile to memory, and stream to web client as zip

Tags: python, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to accomplish something similar to the site http://ogre.adc4gis.com/

I want to be able to manipulate a geojson file, and send it to the client as a shapefile, in a single zip file.

I'm writing the program in python, and I see that the site mentioned above is using Javascript.

I've already been able to save the json as a shapefile with the following command:

```
ogr2ogr.main(["", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "fishnet", "fishnet.json"])
```

This saves our geojson file as 4 separate files in the folder `fishnet`.  I'm wondering how I can avoid saving files to the harddisk and just serve the zip file to the client in memory.

### Update

So far I've zipped it.  Still yet to stream to the client, but I think it should be easy enough to find some resources on `StringIO`.

Basically, what I've done so far is to go ahead and save the files to disk, get the data from them, convert them, and then delete them (after they've been streamed):

```
import ogr2ogr, shutil, uuid
name_of_files = 'custom_name_here'
# random directory name
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501247/best-way-to-generate-random-file-names-in-python
directory_for_files = str(uuid.uuid4())
# -nln gives a custom name to files in folder
# string without .shp gets saved to directory as four files
ogr2ogr.main(['','-f','ESRI Shapefile','-nln', name_of_files, directory_for_files, 'test.json'])
# create zip from directory with same name
shutil.make_archive(directory_for_files, "zip", directory_for_files)
# remove directory
shutil.rmtree(directory_for_files)
```

Answer (score 5):

OGR's vsizip/vismem features are poorly documented, but look at http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/autotest/gcore/vsizip.py for starters. I think applications scale better without trying to do read-process-write in a single thread, but maybe vsizip/vsimem is just right for yours.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe it's easier to work with python's tempfile module:  I could save to a tempfile, zip it, then read it and output to the client.

Comment: I'd love to see what you come up with. Update here when you're done?

Comment: It probably won't be pretty @sgillies.  I've updated with my zipping method so far.  I'll add the stream as well, but it will probably be standard `StringIO` output.

Comment: I added an answer with what I'm using.  It's not perfect, but it suits our purposes. @sgillies

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did (in a Django server environment):

```
import os, ogr2ogr, shutil, uuid, tempfile
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper

# random directory name
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501247/best-way-to-generate-random-file-names-in-python
directory_for_files = str(uuid.uuid4())

# -nln gives a custom name to files in folder
# string without .shp gets saved to directory as four files
ogr2ogr.main(['','-f','ESRI Shapefile','-nln', 'custom_name_here', directory_for_files, 'test.json'])

# create zip from directory with same name
shutil.make_archive(directory_for_files, "zip", directory_for_files)

# remove directory
shutil.rmtree(directory_for_files)

# save zip to memory, then remove
zip_data = open(zip_file, 'rb').read()
os.remove(zip_file)

# save to temporary file (so it will be removed after the http response
tmp_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
tmp_file.write(zip_data)

# output as a zip file to the client
wrapper = FileWrapper(tmp_file)
response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=export-shp.zip"
response['Content-Length'] = tmp_file.tell()
tmp_file.seek(0)

return response
```

Files are created saved to memory and then deleted.  Couldn't figure out how to do it purely in memory, but it seems to serve my purposes at least.

Hope it helps someone out!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use ogr2ogr, but it works entirely in-memory, and is quite easy. First install the pyshp library. Then you can use code like this:

```
import shapefile, io, zipfile
w = shapefile.Writer()
#Create the schema
w.field('name', 'C')

#Fill the shapefile with data
w.point(3, 4)
w.record('some data')

shp, shx, dbf = io.BytesIO(), io.BytesIO(), io.BytesIO()
w.save(shp=shp, shx=shx, dbf=dbf)

zf = io.BytesIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(zf, 'w') as zip: #could also set `compression` if you want
    zip.writestr('foo.shp', shp.getvalue())
    zip.writestr('foo.shx', shx.getvalue())
    zip.writestr('foo.dbf', dbf.getvalue())
    #zip.writestr('foo.prj', the projection string...

#Now the zip data is in `zf.getvalue()`
```